# Ruby code inside script is not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

my google pie chart code is

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ["Work",     50],
          ["Eat",      20],
          ["Commute",  20],
          ["Watch TV", 5],
          ["Sleep",    5]
        ]);
```

and my code is `(<%= @datas.map { |d| [d.name, d.value] }.inspect %>)`
which gives the result

```
([["apple", "10"], ["orange", 20], ["banana", 30], ["grapes", 80], ["papaya", 44]])
```

when i put this result in my google pie chart code directly like this

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["apple", "10"], ["orange", 20], ["banana", 30], ["grapes", 80], ["papaya", 44]])
```

then it works perfectly.
But keeping directly

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= @datas.map { |d| [d.name, d.value] }.inspect %>)
```

does not work. What could be the reason behind this. Do ruby code have some formate to keep inside  Or where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
(<%= @datas.map { |d| [d.name, d.value] }.to_json.html_safe -%>)
```

Comment: I already did this but same problem. I think in this format there is mistake var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= @datas.map { |d| [d.name, d.value] }.inspect %>) But where i dont know and why beacause output of this code directly given works well

Comment: @regmiprem I think the problem was that you got your quotes escaped, edited. By the way, don't you check the created javascript and check how it looks ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20607/discussion-between-regmiprem-and-oldergod)

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

```
@datas = {:apple => 10, :orange => 20, :banana => 30}
@datas.map { |name, value| [name.to_s, value] }
# => [["apple", 10], ["orange", 20], ["banana", 30]]
```

so just write out: <%= @datas.map { |name, value| [name.to_s, value] } %>

Answer (score -1):

you try this .. u change your code according this

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= make_a_chart %>);
```

and place it somewhere in a corresponding helper:

```
 def make_a_chart
  result = []
  result.push make_labels, 
          make_data( 0, "zerohour" ), 
          make_data( 3, "threehours" ),
          make_data( 6, "sixhours" ),
          make_data( 9, "ninehours" ),
          make_data( 12, "twelvehours" )
          return result
          end

  def make_labels
     y = ["Time"]
     for task in Task.all do
     y.append task.name
     end
     return y
  end

 def make_data( time, completeness )
    y = Task.first.created_at + time
      for task in Task.all do
      y.append task[completeness]
   end
 return y
 end
```

Comment: I have to put ruby code inside  it with<%= %> otherwise how can i get value?

Comment: How can i send the value as (o, "zerohour") to (@data.name, "@data.value") I am confused

Comment: give me the contents in the @data variable

Comment: you can see the content in my question. as data.name and data.value